# VirtualBox start Script from host

Tags: unix, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a VM started and want to start a script from the host, inside the vm.
My Test Script looks like:

```
sql /nolog <<!
exit
!
```

when i start from the host:

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "vmname" run --exe "pathToScript" --username xyz --password xyz
```

i receive an error: sql command not found. BUT in the VM it works!

Why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because my env variables werent loaded. So you have to load them in your script like:

```
. .profile  #this file contains your env variables
sql /nolog <<!
exit
!
```